# Expand and collapse nested list with checkboxs c#

Tags: c#, checkbox, treeview

I am new to c# and I need to create a nested list with checkboxes where they are grouped and collapsed in a structured way.

Comment: Choose technology first: wpf, winforms, whatelse ?

Answer (score 0):

There is the [CheckedListBox class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in Winforms. It's really easy to use and I think that it does what you want.